# Expected number of coin tosses

Tags: probability

A fair coin is tossed until either 4 heads or 9 tails obtained ( total). What is the expected number of tosses?

Edit: I calculated the probability. It is 10% for 4 heads and 12% for 9 tails. But how to get expectation from this?

Edit:

For 4 heads:

[image]

For 9 heads:

[image]

Comment: You can grind it out. The number of tosses is anything from $4$ to $12$. Find the probability it is $k$ for these various $k$, and calculate the expectation as usual.

Comment: @André: Oh foo, I misunderstood the problem. Dupe vote retracted.

Comment: @André Nicolas: I calculated the probabilities, but how to get expectations from there?

Comment: Perhaps you could show how your reached your solution, @ReeSSult. That might help others to guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Calculate $p_4$ (the probability the game ends in $4$), $p_5$, and so on up to $p_{12}$. Then the expectation is $4p_4+5p_5+\cdots$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas We appear to be open for business again....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N_{H=4}$ be the number of trials until we count four heads and $N_{T=9}$ that until we count nine tails.

We want to find: $E~=~\mathsf E(\min \{N_{H=4}, N_{T=9}\})$

---

Now, this is just the sum of Heads and Tails under condition that we have either four heads and *less than* nine tails, or nine tails and *at most* four heads.   (Thus including the case where we have both four heads and nine tails).

Letting $H$ count heads and $T$ count tails then:....

---

$$E ~=~ \mathsf E(H{+}T\mid (H{=}4\cap T{<}9)\cup (T{=}9\cap H{\leq}4))$$

Now, since for *disjoint events*† $A,B$, and random variable $X$, we can show (can you?): $$\mathsf E(X\mid {A\cup B}) ~=~ \dfrac{\mathsf E(X\mid A)~\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf E(X\mid B)~\mathsf P(B)}{\mathsf P(A\cup B)}$$

(† that is, disjoint, *non-zero probability-measure* events, to be proper.)

Then...

---

> $$E ~=~ \dfrac{\mathsf E(H{+}T\mid H{=}4,T{<}9)~\mathsf P(H{=}4, T{<}9)+\mathsf E(H{+}T\mid H{\leq}4, T{=}9)~\mathsf P(H{\leq}4, T{=}9)}{\mathsf P(H{=}4, T{<}9)+\mathsf P(T{=}9, H{\leq 4})}$$

Okay, so because we know that $\mathsf P(H{=}h \cap T{=}t) ~=~ \dbinom{h+t}{h}~2^{-(h+t)}$ , then: ...

---

> $$E ~=~ \dfrac{\sum\limits_{t=0}^8\dfrac{4+t}{2^{4+t}}\dbinom{4+t}{4}+\sum\limits_{h=0}^4\dfrac{9+h}{2^{9+h}}\dbinom{9+h}{9}}{\sum\limits_{t=0}^8\dfrac{1}{2^{4+t}}\dbinom{4+t}{4}+\sum\limits_{h=0}^4\dfrac{1}{2^{9+h}}\dbinom{9+h}{9}}$$

---

Simplify and evaluate.

---

**PS Hint:** A short cut to evaluating those series may be obtained by observing that we are dealing with two negative binomials cases: the count of trials until 4 heads before 9 tails, and the count of trials until 9 tails before 4 heads.

Answer (score 3):

The game may last for $4$ rounds, $5$ rounds, and so on up to $12$ rounds. For note that at the end of the $12$-th round, we must have at least $4$ heads or at least $9$ tails, but not both.

For $k=4$ to $12$, let $p_k$ be the probability that the game ends in the $k$-th round. If $X$ is the number of trials, then 
$$E(X)=4p_4+5p_5+\cdots +12p_{12}.$$
It remains to compute the $p_k$.

If $4\le k\le 8$, the game ends in round $k$ if we have $3$ heads in the first $k-1$ trials, and then a head. So
$$p_k=\binom{k-1}{3}(1/2)^k$$
for $k=4$ to $8$.

For $k=9$ to $12$, the game ends in the $k$-th round if on the $k$-th trial we get the $4$-th head or the $9$-th tail. These events are disjoint. Thus for $9\le k\le 12$,
$$p_k=\binom{k-1}{3}(1/2)^k+\binom{k-1}{8}(1/2)^k.$$